# Java Multi-Dimensional Arrays in a Method

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm knew with multi-dimensional arrays and I kind of know the basics but I'm stuck on combining them into a boolean method. In this case, I'm trying to find out how I can make this method simplified which will function as:

- Comparing one array with a location (row:column) to another array (with the same location).
- If all locations from both arrays match, it should return true.

The method below works with what I have for my code but I want to know the proper way on how to not "hard code" the numbers single handedly. Would I need to use a nested for loop for comparing both arrays?

Thanks for the assistance~

```
public static boolean gameIsWon(int[][] workingPuzzle, int[][] solvedPuzzle)
{
    if (workingPuzzle[0][0] == solvedPuzzle[0][0] &&
            workingPuzzle[0][1] == solvedPuzzle[0][1] &&
            workingPuzzle[0][2] == solvedPuzzle[0][2] &&
            workingPuzzle[0][3] == solvedPuzzle[0][3] &&
            workingPuzzle[0][4] == solvedPuzzle[0][4] &&
            workingPuzzle[0][5] == solvedPuzzle[0][5] &&
            workingPuzzle[0][6] == solvedPuzzle[0][6] &&
            workingPuzzle[0][7] == solvedPuzzle[0][7] &&
            workingPuzzle[0][8] == solvedPuzzle[0][8] &&
            workingPuzzle[1][0] == solvedPuzzle[1][0] &&
            workingPuzzle[1][1] == solvedPuzzle[1][1] &&
            workingPuzzle[1][2] == solvedPuzzle[1][2] &&
            workingPuzzle[1][3] == solvedPuzzle[1][3] &&
            workingPuzzle[1][4] == solvedPuzzle[1][4] &&
            workingPuzzle[1][5] == solvedPuzzle[1][5] &&
            workingPuzzle[1][6] == solvedPuzzle[1][6] &&
            workingPuzzle[1][7] == solvedPuzzle[1][7] &&
            workingPuzzle[1][8] == solvedPuzzle[1][8] &&
            workingPuzzle[2][0] == solvedPuzzle[2][0] &&
            workingPuzzle[2][1] == solvedPuzzle[2][1] &&
            workingPuzzle[2][2] == solvedPuzzle[2][2] &&
            workingPuzzle[2][3] == solvedPuzzle[2][3] &&
            workingPuzzle[2][4] == solvedPuzzle[2][4] &&
            workingPuzzle[2][5] == solvedPuzzle[2][5] &&
            workingPuzzle[2][6] == solvedPuzzle[2][6] &&
            workingPuzzle[2][7] == solvedPuzzle[2][7] &&
            workingPuzzle[2][8] == solvedPuzzle[2][8] &&
            workingPuzzle[3][0] == solvedPuzzle[3][0] &&
            workingPuzzle[3][1] == solvedPuzzle[3][1] &&
            workingPuzzle[3][2] == solvedPuzzle[3][2] &&
            workingPuzzle[3][3] == solvedPuzzle[3][3] &&
            workingPuzzle[3][4] == solvedPuzzle[3][4] &&
            workingPuzzle[3][5] == solvedPuzzle[3][5] &&
            workingPuzzle[3][6] == solvedPuzzle[3][6] &&
            workingPuzzle[3][7] == solvedPuzzle[3][7] &&
            workingPuzzle[3][8] == solvedPuzzle[3][8] &&
            workingPuzzle[4][0] == solvedPuzzle[4][0] &&
            workingPuzzle[4][1] == solvedPuzzle[4][1] &&
            workingPuzzle[4][2] == solvedPuzzle[4][2] &&
            workingPuzzle[4][3] == solvedPuzzle[4][3] &&
            workingPuzzle[4][4] == solvedPuzzle[4][4] &&
            workingPuzzle[4][5] == solvedPuzzle[4][5] &&
            workingPuzzle[4][6] == solvedPuzzle[4][6] &&
            workingPuzzle[4][7] == solvedPuzzle[4][7] &&
            workingPuzzle[4][8] == solvedPuzzle[4][8] &&
            workingPuzzle[5][0] == solvedPuzzle[5][0] &&
            workingPuzzle[5][1] == solvedPuzzle[5][1] &&
            workingPuzzle[5][2] == solvedPuzzle[5][2] &&
            workingPuzzle[5][3] == solvedPuzzle[5][3] &&
            workingPuzzle[5][4] == solvedPuzzle[5][4] &&
            workingPuzzle[5][5] == solvedPuzzle[5][5] &&
            workingPuzzle[5][6] == solvedPuzzle[5][6] &&
            workingPuzzle[5][7] == solvedPuzzle[5][7] &&
            workingPuzzle[5][8] == solvedPuzzle[5][8] &&
            workingPuzzle[6][0] == solvedPuzzle[6][0] &&
            workingPuzzle[6][1] == solvedPuzzle[6][1] &&
            workingPuzzle[6][2] == solvedPuzzle[6][2] &&
            workingPuzzle[6][3] == solvedPuzzle[6][3] &&
            workingPuzzle[6][4] == solvedPuzzle[6][4] &&
            workingPuzzle[6][5] == solvedPuzzle[6][5] &&
            workingPuzzle[6][6] == solvedPuzzle[6][6] &&
            workingPuzzle[6][7] == solvedPuzzle[6][7] &&
            workingPuzzle[6][8] == solvedPuzzle[6][8] &&
            workingPuzzle[7][0] == solvedPuzzle[7][0] &&
            workingPuzzle[7][1] == solvedPuzzle[7][1] &&
            workingPuzzle[7][2] == solvedPuzzle[7][2] &&
            workingPuzzle[7][3] == solvedPuzzle[7][3] &&
            workingPuzzle[7][4] == solvedPuzzle[7][4] &&
            workingPuzzle[7][5] == solvedPuzzle[7][5] &&
            workingPuzzle[7][6] == solvedPuzzle[7][6] &&
            workingPuzzle[7][7] == solvedPuzzle[7][7] &&
            workingPuzzle[7][8] == solvedPuzzle[7][8] &&
            workingPuzzle[8][0] == solvedPuzzle[8][0] &&
            workingPuzzle[8][1] == solvedPuzzle[8][1] &&
            workingPuzzle[8][2] == solvedPuzzle[8][2] &&
            workingPuzzle[8][3] == solvedPuzzle[8][3] &&
            workingPuzzle[8][4] == solvedPuzzle[8][4] &&
            workingPuzzle[8][5] == solvedPuzzle[8][5] &&
            workingPuzzle[8][6] == solvedPuzzle[8][6] &&
            workingPuzzle[8][7] == solvedPuzzle[8][7] &&
            workingPuzzle[8][8] == solvedPuzzle[8][8]
        )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Nested `for` loops...

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn about loops.

And about storing a two-dimensional matrix in a one-dimensional array using index mapping (which is easier to handle than a two-dimensional array).

But in this particular case:

```
return java.util.Arrays.deepEquals(workingPuzzle, solvedPuzzle);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, although I have yet covered on this. I will look into this further.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested for loops based on the array lengths.

```
 public static boolean gameIsWon(int[][] workingPuzzle, int[][] solvedPuzzle) {
  if(workingPuzzle.length != solvedPuzzle.length) {
      return false; 
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < workingPuzzle.length; i++) {
    if(workingPuzzle[i].length != solvedPuzzle[i].length) {
      return false;
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < workingPuzzle[i].length; j++) {
      if(workingPuzzle[i][j] != solvedPuzzle[i][j]) {
          return false; 
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what the first line of the for loop is checking?

Comment: The rows are checked by the if statement outside the for loop and each "row" is check inside the for loop (the first statement inside the for loop). Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, this worked. It helps to see what I need to structure.

Comment: Thanks both for the help!